# Verbs in time clauses and 'if' clauses

Tags: modal-verbs, sequence-of-tenses

On this page, https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/verbs-in-time-clauses-and-if-clauses, there is a section called "Making hypotheses" It says: some conditional clauses are like hypotheses, so we use past tense forms. We use past tense forms to talk about something that does not happen or is not happening in the present. One of the examples from that section is given below:

> If Jack was playing, they would probably win.

The tense in this sentence confuses me. If I were to rewrite it, I would say, "If Jack was playing, they **could/would have probably won**. Shouldn't we use the past modal could have/would have here? I am also not sure, whether "could have" or "would have" should be used. As it is a result of the past unreal condition that we are talking about, my choice would be - would have. Could have also sounds appropriate because it is about the possibility in the past which didn't happen. Can someone explain to me how to approach this?

Comment: Your rewrite uses "was" to express past  time, but the "was" in _If Jack was playing, they would probably win_ does not refer to past time; instead it has to do with modality, not time.

Comment: *If Jack was playing, they would probably win* uses ***was*** and modal ***would*** to reference a "counterfactual" assertion (context requires that Jack ***isn't*** playing, with the strong implication that they ***will*** therefore ***lose***). If you change the modal to a "Perfect" form *(...they'd probably **have won**)* you're changing the meaning (the Perfect version only works if they've ***already lost***, at time of utterance).

Comment: Okay. Thanks,guys. If I am changing the modal verb to a perfect form,  shouldn’t I be using “had played” instead of “was playing”: “If Jack had played, they would have probably won” ?